# Tabs bootstrap não voltam

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Fiz as tabs no bootstrap porem elas vão uma vez uma para outras mais depois que foi clicado em cada uma ela não da permissão de clicar novamente.

```
<div id="tabss" style="text-align: center;">
                  <li><a href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">Biografia</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#noticias" data-toggle="tab">Últimas Notícias</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#agendas" data-toggle="tab">Agendas</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#recados" data-toggle="tab">Recados</a></li>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="bio">Bio</div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="noticias">Noticias</div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="agendas">Agendas</div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="recados">Recados</div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os elementos `<li>` não podem ser inseridos dentro do elemento `<div>`. Na [semântica do bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), eles devem ser inseridos dentro da tag `<ul>`.

O HTML correto seria:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="tabss" style="text-align: center;" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">Biografia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#noticias" data-toggle="tab">Últimas Notícias</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#agendas" data-toggle="tab">Agendas</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#recados" data-toggle="tab">Recados</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="bio">Bio</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="noticias">Noticias</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="agendas">Agendas</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="recados">Recados</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. @MarcusVinicius